# BHO or Command Button for explorer

Tags: windows, windows-shell, bho, windows-explorer, commandbar

I am trying to develop a command button that would appear on windows explorer. I can do this for an NSE but what I want to do is make the button visible on every explorer window. I want it to work for windows 7 and vista. I know it is possible as I have seen office Groove do it, and I am not sure if I have to implement the IExplorer(...) interfaces or just create a simple BHO (Browser Helper Button) that is registered for windows explorer and not IE.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing, with no luck so far ([My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744980/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-all-windows-explorer-instances)).

What i did manage to learn is that "BHO is the way to go". After trying tons of different ways i found it is the simplest way to hook to all windows explorer instances.

Within your BHO code you could filter out instances of IE, but there is probably a registry way to do it also.

Good luck, and let us know if you figured it out.

Comment: thx for the answer man, however I've already skipped the whole thing and went on using a toolband as it turned out I needed more than what a single button can offer.... thx for the reply and here is an up vote for sharing.